# Web Service Client(Console App) not working on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008-r2, webservices-client

I am trying to consume an ASMX Web Service in a console app, its working fine in Windows 7,Windows Server 2012 Standard,Windows Server 2008 R2 DataCenter,Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, But its not working in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition which is the deployment server.

I tried consuming the ASMX web service using Web Reference and Service Reference as well but its not helping.
Its throwing up the following error,

Message:There is an error in XML document (1, 331491).

Inner Exception : System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 331491.

The scenario is that i call the web service and it returns me an XML i am not able to receive the XML on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.

Please provide suggestions on this I need to resolve this ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused due to missing certificate on that Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition I had figured it out by looking at the certificate in IE while the web service site was opened and also this web service was changed to WCF so I was getting different errors and when I authorized myself to connect to the internet the client app threw an exception saying that certificate is not trusted so I installed the necessary certificates and it was solved.